# How to change background/foreground color on "all" existing terminals

Tags: terminal, gnome, colors, gnome-terminal, xterm

I am looking for a command line way to change the background & foreground colors of all open terminal   (and also for any new terminal, the new settings should be applied).

Using something like `setterm -term linux -back blue -fore white -clear`
only the terminal in which I execute the command  is affected. I want to change for all terminals, without needed to close/reopen any terminal.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the output of the `setterm` command to the device file of the terminal.

```
for i in {0..3}; do setterm -term linux -back blue -fore white -clear > /dev/pts/$i; done
```

Comment: thank you so much. it works and i learnt something new about /dev/pts