# Set xterm text color

Tags: gnome, xterm

in my gnome terminal i can change the profile preferences to set the text color to green. i'm not talking about the prompt (this is already set up in blue how i want it) just talking about the general text color when i run commands like `echo` for example. What should i add to my `.bashrc` file to do this for the linux terminals? (eg. for the `ctrl+alt+f1` terminal) i want green text.

i am running debian 7.

Comment: [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/248299/how-to-change-background-foreground-color-on-all-existing-terminals) may hold the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this in `~/.bashrc`:

```
# set the default text color. this only works in tty (eg $TERM == "linux"), not pts (eg $TERM == "xterm")
setterm -background black -foreground green -store
```

Answer (score 2):

this `.bashrc` comes close but is still not quite right:

```
black_foreground=30
red_foreground=31
green_foreground=32
yellow_foreground=33
blue_foreground=34
magenta_foreground=35
cyan_foreground=36
white_foreground=37

black_background=40
red_background=41
green_background=42
yellow_background=43
blue_background=44
magenta_background=45
cyan_background=46
white_background=47

reset_color=0

normal_chars=0
bold_chars=1
underlined_chars=4
blinking_chars=5
reverse_chars=7

start_prompt_coloring="\e[${bold_chars};${cyan_foreground}m"
end_prompt_coloring="\e[0m"
start_text_coloring="\e[${green_foreground}m"
PS1="${start_prompt_coloring}[\u@\h \W] \$${end_prompt_coloring} ${start_text_coloring}"
```

this gives the desired green text up until i run a command such as `ls -l --color=auto` which is colored, and then the ls command sets its own white color for that command only:

[image: sample bash terminal with colored text]

i do not want the output of `ls -l` to be white (white is the current terminal default) - i want to change the default terminal text to green. please provide a better answer if you know one!

Comment: This answer has one issue, at least for me, that with this setting, now if I type a long command it wraps around on the same line, overwriting what was displayed there.